# OpenGL Cubemap : Writing to mipmap

Tags: c++, opengl

**[Objectives]** I need to write to a CubeMap's specific mipmap level in OpenGL 4+. Each mipmap levels is blurrier the deeper the level is.

**[Problem]** The problem is that I have the same image over all mipmap levels if I write only on level 0, and nothing at all if I try to write only on other mipmap level.

**[Update]** I'm pretty sure the problem is `textureLod` always clamp to the base LOD 0. Whatever mipmap level I try to get through it, it returns the base LOD.

Here is my cubemap generation (I'm trying to have 6 mipmap levels, counting the base):

```
GLuint PreFilteredEnvTex;
glGenTextures(1, &PreFilteredEnvTex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, PreFilteredEnvTex);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 5);
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGB16F, 512, 512, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, 0);
}
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

Utils::checkGlError("Generate PreFilteredEnvMap");
```

And here an example of my attempt to write to each mipmap levels :

```
//Compute pre filtered environnement maps
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboManager["fx"]);
glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

const int MIPMAPLEVELS = 6;
const int MIPMAPBASELEVELSIZE = 512;
int MipMapTextureSize;
glBindVertexArray(vaoManager["cube"]);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, skybox->texture_id);
Shader* PreEnvFilter = shaderManager["PreEnvFilter"];
PreEnvFilter->use();

glm::vec3 EyePosition = glm::vec3(0.f);
// Light space matrices
glm::mat4 CubeMapProjection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(90.f), 1.f, 1.f, 100.f);
std::vector<glm::mat4> worldToLight;
worldToLight.push_back(CubeMapProjection * glm::lookAt(EyePosition, EyePosition + glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0), glm::vec3(0.0, -1.0, 0.0)));
worldToLight.push_back(CubeMapProjection * glm::lookAt(EyePosition, EyePosition + glm::vec3(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0), glm::vec3(0.0, -1.0, 0.0)));
worldToLight.push_back(CubeMapProjection * glm::lookAt(EyePosition, EyePosition + glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0), glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)));
worldToLight.push_back(CubeMapProjection * glm::lookAt(EyePosition, EyePosition + glm::vec3(0.0, -1.0, 0.0), glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, -1.0)));
worldToLight.push_back(CubeMapProjection * glm::lookAt(EyePosition, EyePosition + glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), glm::vec3(0.0, -1.0, 0.0)));
worldToLight.push_back(CubeMapProjection * glm::lookAt(EyePosition, EyePosition + glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, -1.0), glm::vec3(0.0, -1.0, 0.0)));
for (GLuint i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    PreEnvFilter->SetMatrix4(("ViewMatrix[" + to_string(i) + "]").c_str(), worldToLight[i]);
PreEnvFilter->SetInt("EnvMapSampler", 0);
PreEnvFilter->SetMatrix4("Model", glm::mat4());
//For each faces compute all mipmaps levels
for (unsigned int j = 0; j < MIPMAPLEVELS; ++j)
{
    //For each mipmap level, render the filtered environnement in it
    MipMapTextureSize = std::max(1, MIPMAPBASELEVELSIZE / (1 << j));
    glViewport(0, 0, MipMapTextureSize, MipMapTextureSize);
    //glViewport(0, 0, MIPMAPBASELEVELSIZE, MIPMAPBASELEVELSIZE);
    float roughness = (j + 0.5f) / MIPMAPLEVELS;
    PreEnvFilter->SetFloat("Roughness", roughness);
    //Bind to the current buffer
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, PreFilteredEnvTex, j);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 12 * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)0);
}

PreEnvFilter->unuse();
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);

Utils::checkGlError("Initialize PreFilteredEnvMap");
```

I'm sure my shader is working, because if I'm looping over all mipmap levels and drawing only to the base level I have a good looking result :
[The result if I'm only writing to level 0 for all mipmap levels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rL3Z3.png)

The cubemap is printed with the following fragment shader (TexCoords is modified according to the face I want to draw) :

```
#version 430

uniform int MipMapLevel;
uniform samplerCube CubeMap;
in vec3 TexCoords;
out vec4 Color;

void main()
{
    Color = textureLod(CubeMap, TexCoords, MipMapLevel);
}
```

And if I'm writing to all mipmap levels, I have the same image on all mipmap levels (actually if I write only to level 0 I have the same result on all mipmap levels as well )

[Same result, different mipmap levels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pniMi.png)

My conclusion is as followed :

- My mipmap generation is not good, but I've read the specs and glGenerateMipmap should have done the job
- I have a problem when trying to bind the mipmap level throught glFramebufferTexture, but once again it doesn't seems wrong to me
- My shader to draw the cubemap is not working as I think it should ? I've never used textureLod before, but as far as I know, I am using it right here, right ?

If someone as already done something similar, I would really appreciate some help ! After all the time I spent on it, I'm still not able to do this simple thing in OpenGL when I did it whithout problems in DX11 :(

P.S : OpenGL does not report any errors

Comment: 2 observations: 1. You never set the shader parameter 'MipMapLevel'. 2. You pass a constant '5' as the level to glFrameBufferTexture instead of 'j'.

Comment: Sorry for 2. should have been edited, i'm actually passing j, I was testing with 5 to see if something wrote in mipmap level 5 and it doesn't. For 1., maybe I was not very clear, but the shader you are referring to is only the shader which produced the images of the question (so, only my "debug draw"). The shader used in the program is more complicated, but as I said, I'm 100% sure it works.

Comment: OK, I think you need [glFrameBufferTexture2D](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glFramebufferTexture.xhtml), which allows you to specify the cube map face you want to draw to. This means you should have two nested loops: for all 6 faces, for all mipmap levels; resulting in 6 * #mipmap_levels draw calls.

Comment: Actually I'm rendering to all the faces at once with a geometry shader (thats why I have 6 view matrix and I render a unit cube ). I could try to render to one face mipmap and see if it works, but I think this is only a problem of mipmap not of rendering to the cubemap (because you can see on the pictures that it is actually working if I'm using only the base level of the mipmap).

Comment: "*I have the same image on all mipmap levels*" What do you mean by "same image"? You *can't* have the same image; the mipmaps are smaller and therefore not the same.

Comment: It's also not clear which one is supposed to be "right" and which is not. Are you saying that `glGenerateMipmaps` is not generating mipmaps properly, or are you saying that your attempt to create mipmaps through rendering is not working? In the second case, are you calling `glGenerateMipmaps` when you create the texture?

Comment: @NicolBolas Well, that's the thing ! If I write on mipmap level 0, I have exactly the same texture when I call textureLod on another mipmap level. Well, I'm not sure `glGenerateMipmaps` did generate my mipmaps (how can I ?), and it seems like when I want to render to a mipmap level it is not working, but when I use a cubemap without mipmaps I can write on the base level 0 without any problem.

Comment: @Toffanim: What do you mean by "write on mipmap level 0"? Do you mean "render to?" Also, how are you not sure if `glGenerateMipmaps` generated your mipmaps? Did you call it?

Comment: Write on mipmap level 0 = Render with `glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, PreFilteredEnvTex, 0);`, you can see in the first code snippet that I am calling `glGenerateMipmaps`. I think the problem is `textureLod` always return the base level when I'm trying to use it, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying almost everything, I've finally make it works by generating my cubemap as follow :

```
GLuint PreFilteredEnvTex;
glGenTextures(1, &PreFilteredEnvTex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, PreFilteredEnvTex);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 5);

for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGB16F, 512, 512, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, 0);
}   
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
```

I've change the min filter to `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR` and call `glGenerateMipmap` at the end, instead of doing like in [this link](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Creating_a_complete_texture).

Thanks for your interest :)